# JSDoc - Types for multiple declarations, one after the other

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, jsdoc

I am currently using this:

```js
    /** @type {TagsLevel} */
    export let list;
    /** @type {string} */
    export let tagListName;
    
    /** @type {string | null} */
    let srcTag = null;
    /** @type {number | null} */
    let srcTagNum = null;
    /** @type {number | null} */
    let srcLevelNum = null;
```

It's not very clear.

I wish I could use it that way:

```js
    /** @type {TagsLevel} */
    /** @type {string} */
    export let list;
    export let tagListName;
    
    /** @type {string | null} */
    /** @type {number | null} */
    /** @type {number | null} */
    let srcTag = null;
    let srcTagNum = null;
    let srcLevelNum = null;
```

This should work identically to the previous code.

**Is there a JSDoc syntax that enables something like this?**

If not, I would like to know where to make the suggestion that support for such a case be introduced.

**WHY THIS?**

I am following the syntax of the function - `@param`. It's not identical, but it's very similar:

```js
// Parameters may be declared in a variety of syntactic forms
/**
 * @param {string}  p1 - A string param.
 * @param {string=} p2 - An optional param (Google Closure syntax)
 * @param {string} [p3] - Another optional param (JSDoc syntax).
 * @param {string} [p4="test"] - An optional param with a default value
 * @returns {string} This is the result
 */
function stringsStringStrings(p1, p2, p3, p4) {
  // TODO
}
```

---

The alternative - this:

```js
    /** @type {TagsLevel} */ export let list;
    /** @type {string} */    export let tagListName;
    
    /** @type {string | null} */ let srcTag = null;
    /** @type {number | null} */ let srcTagNum = null;
    /** @type {number | null} */ let srcLevelNum  = null;
```

But it's not very clear either, and it makes the line very long.

Comment: Needing one or two lines to find out what the type is, seems much clearer than needing a variable amount of context *and* mental processing to narrow down what the type is. I'm not sure what you mean by "transparent" here.

Comment: @VLAZ Function `@param @param @param` has almost this syntax, so I don't know what your problem is. Do you think it is not very clear? - https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsdoc-supported-types.html#param-and-returns

Comment: If there is a block with 10 lines describing types with another block of 10 lines of variables following it, then in order to find out the type, you need to read back 10 lines. All the while keeping track of how many variables you passed, how many type definitions you passed and what the total number of them is. Just to try to find out what `let foo` is supposed to be. If the blocks have other than 10 lines each, then the maths changes. The more lines, the harder it is to keep track of everything.

Comment: But I'm not proposing to remove the existing syntax.
You use where you are more comfortable.
Don't panic ;P